# How To Use Custom Nameserver On Free Cloudflare?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I have a problem.

I own a small hosting company. I am trying to add Cloudflare to my site as a free CDN. The only problem is when I sign up I have to change the nameservers to their nameservers. I already have nameserver DNS set up through GoDaddy, so how do I add them to CloudFlare? My main site uses my company's nameservers already but whenever I add them the site goes offline.

When I go into Cloudflare's DNS records I click on the dropdown, click NS, and there's two boxes that say 'Name' and 'Nameserver'. Does this mean I input 'NS1' into 'Name' and 'NS1.DOMAIN.COM' into 'Nameserver'? Where do I input my server's IP addresses?

Is there another way of accomplishing this with the free version of Cloudflare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just impossible. Option to have custom name servers available only on Business and Enterprise. See https://www.cloudflare.com/plans.

Also, you might mistaken. You must change name servers in your domain register settings, not on CloudFlare.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. Why does it give me the option to add NS records if it's not possible?

Comment: @OWENNNN It's diffrent. You could do something like: 1. Change in your GoDaddy name servers to CloudFlare's; 2. Set NS records in CloudFlare to GoDaddy's or your own. (if GoDaddy is also your hosting or something)
Anyway, NS records must refer server, that can resolve your domain.

Comment: My domain is with GoDaddy, my dedicated server is ServerHub. Not sure how I would accomplish this :p

Comment: I think ServerHub gave you IP address or domain of your server. If it's IP then you just need to create `A` record on CloudFlare, referencing that IP. Same thing with domain, only record type have to be `CNAME` in that case.

Comment: Is there another CDN/DDoS protection service that offers a free wildcard SSL?

Comment: As far as I remember - CloudFlare, lol. Just enable HTTPS for domain and add wildcard `CNAME` / `A`, it should work. Also there is WoSign.

Answer (score 0):

An old question (no doubt you found the answer long ago), but nevertheless still an interesting one!  I recently faced this issue and would like to share what I did.

If I understand the question correctly, you are using child nameservers at your registrar to point your customers' domains to your server?

In cloudflare, after you have added your primary domain, you can also specify the NS record to allow customer domains to continue to use your custom / child nameservers at your registrar.

In the DNS records control panel, simply choose NS from the dropdown field, then in the Name field, add your child nameserver, then in Ip4address field, add the nameserver so it looks like e.g.

NS   yourdomain.com   managed by ns1.yourchildnameserver.com

Do the same for NS2 and your customer domains should continue to resolve without any issues.

In the end of course, it would be better to add each customer domain into CF ad point their DNS directly to your server, but the above steps should work as an interim measure.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Is it possible to make DNS LOOP?